# Where can I find a list of Sharepoint 2010 query string parameters?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, query-string

An answer that, will no doubt, provoke a lot of lmgtfy responses - but I seriously can't seem to find a list of available Sharepoint 2010 query string parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find list of some of those parameters here:

[Querystring parameters you should not use in your SharePoint application](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/30/querystring-parameters-you-should-not-use-in-your-sharepoint-application.aspx)

The article is about names you should avoid for your own parameters, but at the same time it gives you the information about the ones used by SharePoint :).